# How to include parameter in sql command in access VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am new to Access VBA. I am passing a parameter (t) which is the result of a function(myfunc) to a table(myTable), it has ID and time column. Here is my code. It does not work. Where is the problem? Thanks.

```
Sub test()
Dim timetem As String
Dim t As String * 50

timetem = DLookup("[time]", "myTable", "[ID]=1")

t = myfunc(timetem)

DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE myTable SET [time] ='" & t & "'WHERE [ID] =1;"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please post the specific error code you're getting.
There are two issues with your code,
Firstly, what datatype is [time]?

If the time column in the database is not a string, this code will not work.
You should match the data type of timetem with the data type of the [time] column in your DB.

If time should be a date/time field then t should be escaped with # instead of '

I think there should also be a space here:

```
"'WHERE [ID]
```

should probably be

```
"' WHERE [ID]
```

Other pointers: You don't need to specify the size of t. Actually if you're trying to pass a date type as a string you probably would need to use the Format() function.

Also, DLookup is evil.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I matched the data type by 'Dim t as Date  DoCmd.RunSQL ("UPDATE TheTable  SET TheTable.time = # " & t & " # WHERE TheTable.ID =1;")' and it worked out